# Installation error in Ubuntu - The settings.php file does not exist

Tags: 8, installation

I've installed Drupal 6\7\8 in WAMP environments for about a hundred times, but I don't recall ever having the following instllation error, which I encountered only in Ubuntu desktop 15.10, Apache2 (2.4.12), Drupal 8:

> **The Settings file does not exist**.
>
> The Drupal installer requires that
>   you create a ./sites/default/settings.php as part of the installation
>   process. Copy the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file to
>   ./sites/default/settings.php. More details about installing Drupal are
>   available in INSTALL.txt.

As the error suggest, I've tried to create it myself from the default.settings.php as the install error suggests and there was no change. I could surly import it from another Drupal 8 site in my WAMP environment, but I would thank any Drupal developer who would shed some light on why this would even happen?

Maybe it happened due to the fact that in the first time there was an install attempt, the folders permissions were not 777 (now they are - changed recursively for the site's folder only and at least temporarily).

Will thank you for your help,

### Update

[image]

Comment: If the web server does not have permission to write to the default directory on installation, then it cannot copy the file itself, and thus you must do it yourself and make the settings file writable.

Comment: But it does have now I changed the site's folder recursively to 777 and I wrote I already tried creating the settings.php file from the default.settings.php ("template") file...

Comment: Can you post the output of ls -al sites/default?

Comment: @Berdir, I've update the question,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to the folder where you installed drupal. Ex:

```
cd /var/www/drupal
```

then

```
sudo chown www-data -R sites
```

Now try installing again.

Comment: Thank you !!! Can you please explain what was done here? I'm very new to Linux in general and understands it only partially...

Comment: BTW, can If I'll do sudo chmod -R 755 to the folder var, will it cancel the command you gave me?

Comment: www-data is the user under which the Apache web server runs. This also means that everything done by Apache (especially including PHP scripts) will be done with the permissions of user www-data

Comment: @benos, no it won't, and yes don't leave it 777, lol.

Comment: the `chown` command is to change the owner user to the folder. `-R` means all folders inside. As per your picture before, the owner was root.

Comment: On a Mac the Apache user might most likely be `www` or `_www`.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I'm still seeing "The Settings file does not exist."  The file exists and is in the correct location, owned by the web server and for now has 777 perms.  Installer still doesn't work.  Drupal 8.2.4.  Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2d. 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4.

Comment: Update:  My problem was that I had configured the site in apache to listen to port 8000 instead of 80.

Comment: I have the same problem but in mac